# dbms_scheduler.run_job('jobName) fails to run

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I'm trying to run a scheduled job manually, the job looksa like this

```
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'PLAYER_STATE_UPDATER',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=0', /* every day at Midnight */
   job_class          =>  'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   enabled            =>  true,
   auto_drop          =>  false);
```

Now when I run the procedure using `execute PLAYER_STATE_UPDATER` I can see the desired result , but the job is failing to execute as shown by

```
select log_date, job_name, status, run_duration
from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name='UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES' or status='FAILED';


    LOG_DATE                    JOB_NAME        STATUS   RUN_DURATION 
------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
23-AUG-11 00.20.24.288887000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
22-AUG-11 10.27.24.537659000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
22-AUG-11 10.28.50.447042000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
22-AUG-11 10.30.30.018891000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 10.59.02.332579000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 10.59.15.980730000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 10.59.27.823131000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 11.01.04.798364000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
24-AUG-11 00.20.24.419251000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 00.20.24.299180000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0    
25-AUG-11 09.35.24.798535000 +01:00 UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES    FAILED    0 0:0:0.0
```

And executing the job manually is failing too `dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES');` with the error

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES')
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

What am I missing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you're trying to run the job manually, it looks like you are simply not using the correct syntax in SQL Developer.  You need to use `execute dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES')`.  Of course that doesn't explain why the job is failing.

My guess is there's something wrong with the job configuration such that it can't even start; but I don't see what it is.  You might try including the schema name in the `job_action` to make sure it is not looking in the wrong schema.

Is there anything of interest in the other columns of `dba_scheduler_job_run_details` -- particularly `error#` or `additional_info`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have looked at the error code first, its 6576, adding the schema name to the procedure solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

you're running manually the JOB as:

```
dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES')
```

Oracle think this is a command, but is not, that's why you receive error message, "Unknown command".

The **correct way** to execute it is:

```
BEGIN
   dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES');
END;
```

Once you achieved to execute it, if your schema **do not have enough privileges**, then you will see something like "Object do not exist or you don't have permissions", which is probably **the root cause of the issue**.

Best Regards :)

Comment: You can also do `exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('UPDATE_PLAYER_STATES');`